# installing Visual Editor extension on my mediawiki

Tags: installation, mediawiki, visual-editor

Is there anybody to help me on this case?
Please tell me how can I install this extension on my media wiki?
I don't have Debian/Linux operating system on my pc.
Thanks in advance
Marziya

I just download this extension and I thought on YouTube there is installation tutorial but there isn't at least I couldn't find anything that help me.
because they used code and programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much to do. As for any extension, download it, uncompress it into the "extension" directory present in your mediawiki directory, and load it by adding the line :

> wfLoadExtension( 'VisualEditor' );

at the end of the file `LocalSettings.php` which is also in the mediawiki directory.